# Check for whether or not a hyperlink is a file

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, xhtml

So I need to be able to tell whether or not a link leads to a file. Now I've been able to manually hardcode some css for file links on pages however there is also a site wide search which results don't produce any way to differentiate between link types.

Is there some sort of php library function I can call that will distinguish the difference? Or is there some sort of clever work around that I can use?

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna do. What you mean by "a link leads to a file or another page" ?

Comment: what u want to do if link doesnt have file in it?

Comment: You can use curl to fetch headers from the link and check if the content-type is text/html or something else.

Comment: I've never used any cURL. I have no idea what it entails... a quick php manual search simply produces more results than I can handle. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not a reliable way. "File" and "page" are a same thing, both are just files. Another one happens to be HTML (or eventually will spit out HTML) and other one happens to be something else.

What you could do is create css selectors like

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {color: red;}
```

which will make all `a` elements whose `href` attribute value ends with `.pdf` to be colored red.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not really sure why I previously thought that wouldn't work... I must have overlooked it. I apologize.